# using compilation symbols(?) in custom build events VS2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to make a build event and I want to know if it is possible to use symbols that you define with #define TEST.

I am guessing it would have to be done using custom macros defined in the project file.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to directly import `#define TEST` constructions from your *.cs files (ok, it's possible, but I think it doesn't worth it).

Instead, you can define build configuration (or use standard Debug and Release), and add properties to your *.csproj project file like this:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug'">
    <TestDefined>yes</TestDefined>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Thus, you define a constant for `Debug` configuration. Then, you can use it in build event conditions like

```
if ('$(TestDefined)' == 'yes') ...
```

Alternatively, you can define constants using visual editor for project properties from inside VS.Net, they are stored & initialized in similar way by VS.Net:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU'">
    ...
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    ...
</PropertyGroup>
```

They require more coding to parse, but it's easier to edit constants themselves.